# Is there a way to pass custom variables while loading html file in php by using htmlLoadFile function?

Tags: php, html, variables, load, domdocument

I am trying to pass specific variables to the html file which has extension of .php 
for e.g I am trying to load main.php by using loadHTMLFile() function in another file.  but when I try to add code like this

```
"<?php echo "hello world"?>"
```

and running the website and checking it's inspect elemnt this php code is commented, do you have any idea or way around of this?

I have tried using semicolon like this

```
'.<?php echo "hello world" ?>.'
```

also

```
'.echo "hello world".'
```

but it does not works

```
      function loadHtml($loadfile){
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTMLFile($loadfile);
        echo $doc->saveHtml() ;
    }
```

and is called in index.php like this:

```
     loadHtml("./views/html/shop/main.php");
```

about errors there are no errors just that I can't call the php variable or function or anythin php related to the main.php file because anything that has php tags around it is commented. Please help me if you know solution or way around this.

Comment: Well making an HTTP request instead of reading from the local file system could “fix” this … But whether that’s advisable, rather depends on the specific circumstances in which you need this. If this is for some administrative task or something only, that would probably be okay - but if you do this on every page load, it might be rather detrimental regarding performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents()` with `eval()`

Example: `eval(file_get_contents('file.php'));`

But you will either have to remove the PHP tags from the file you want to include or do like this: `eval('?>'. file_get_contents('file.php'));`

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't use just `require("./views/html/shop/main.php")` or `include("./views/html/shop/main.php")`?

Using `eval()` is not great idea, because it call script in special context, and is it unsafe, less effective to power and little hard to debug errors in future (stack trace log is not contain source of eval files).